# Converting string into array of ints ex String st = "1 2 3 4 5" into ar=[1,2,3,4,5]

Tags: java, arrays, string, stringtokenizer, parseint

I am reading in a string, as an entire line of numbers, separated by spaces, ie ie `1 2 3 4 5`. I want to convert them into an array of integers, so that I can manipulate them. But this code doesn't work. It says incompatible types.

```
String str = br.readLine();
int[] array = new int[4];
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(str," ", true);
boolean expectDelim = false;
int i = 0;

while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tok.nextToken();
    ar[i] = Integer.parseInt(token);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: "incompatible types" - on which line? As it stands, this won't compile: you've mixed `ar` and `array`. Please give us a complete sample! And in any case your array is too short for 12345: why not use an ArrayList?

Comment: at which line you getting compilation error

Comment: Also, [the JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) says: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: Also you are passing true in the StringTokenizer constructor. So you will return delimiters as token. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, I get NumberFormatExeption because you decided that StringTokenizer should also return delimiters (space) by using `true` as last argument of its constructor. Also "1 2 3 4 5" represents 5 elements so array of size `4` will not be able to hold them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `String s = "1 2 3 4 5"` then you can split it into separate bits like this:

```
String[] bits = s.split(" ");
```

Now you have to put them into an `int[]` by converting each one:

```
int[] nums = new int[bits.length];
int i=0;
for (String s: bits)
    nums[i++] = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

This will loop through each of the small strings in the split array, convert it to an integer, and put it into the new array.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the delimiters. Change this:

```
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(str," ", true);
```

to this:

```
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(str," ");
```

What's happening in your code is that it's trying to parse  (space) as an `int`.

Alternatively, nowadays most people would just use `String.split(...)`, as pointed out by chiastic-security.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 style solution:

```
String input = "1 2 3 4 5";

int[] numbers = Arrays.stream(input.split("\\s+"))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Comment: Yay, Java 8! You could directly `stream()` arrays, no intermediate `asList()` required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to convert a String consisting of whitespace-separated numbers to an `int[]`:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;

public class ConvertString {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final String s = "1 2 3 4 5";
        final int[] numbers = stream(s.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

        // Print it as a demo.
        for (final int number : numbers)
            System.out.format("%s ", number);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```